# In Visual Studio pressing F7 while vising an aspx document toggles the code behind but sometimes it toggles the designer

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio pressing F7 while vising an aspx document toggles the code behind but sometimes it toggles the designer.

I don't EVER want the designer when I press F7... so how do I make it the same all the time?

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem.. I can't figure out why it sometimes show the designer and sometimes not. I wish I could disable the designer all together.